# How to retrieve x and y coordinates in torch tensor?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, tensor, libtorch

I'm working with a mobilenetv2 model. So I'm working with detection and I'm able to get the score (how close an object resembles something on the training set list) and the object name.

I just need to figure out how to get the x and y coordinates as well as the width and height of the detection. I've provided a real-time example (as comments) of how the variables looked like throughout runtime process. I'm dealing with a tensor shape of [3, 224, 224]

```
    const ImageFrame& frame =
            cc->Inputs().Index(0).Value().Get<ImageFrame>();
    auto tensor = ImageFrameToNormalizedTensor(frame, 0, 255.);
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(tensor->unsqueeze(0));
       // tensor->unsqueeze(0).sizes() = [1, 3, 224, 224]
    auto result = model.forward(inputs).toTensor();
    result = result.squeeze(0);
       // result.argmax(0) = 733
       // result.index({result.argmax(0)}) = 7.50187


    auto output_detections = absl::make_unique<Detections>();
    const auto class_id = result.argmax(0).item<int>();
    const auto score = result.index({result.argmax(0)}).item<float>();
    Detection detection;
    detection.add_label_id(class_id);
    detection.add_score(score);
```

I'm able to get the class_id and score. Could anyone please guide me on how to get the x,y,w (width) and h (height).